# I cant execute test with dbunit on materialized view

Tags: spring, testing, dbunit

I want to test DAO layer with dbunit and spring, in which I execute select request in materialized view.

I have this exception:

> *java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view***

The problem is I can't modify `TableType` in `DatabaseConfigBean`. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are trying to insert data into a materialized view using dbunit. This does not work, because ... well ... it's a view.

Create the data in the underlying tables instead.

Also make sure the materialized view refreshes it's data, before your actual test runs.